# How to notify that the element in mysql is the same as input?

Tags: php, mysql

For example in Python using array:

```
arr = [13, 10,  23, 35]
Input = int(input())
for i in arr:
     if Input == i:
          print("Same")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send ajax request to this php code:

```
<?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database_name');
    $sql="SELECT search_element from table_name";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        if($row['search_element']==/* required value */)
        {
            echo 'success';
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Later in your js if the ajax returns success, you may perform required action.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditional statement with a `in` operator

```
select case when input in ( 13, 10, 23, 35 ) then
         'same'
       end as output
  from tab
```

where `tab` is your database table

or use `exists` as

```
  select 'same' as output     
    from tab
   where exists ( select 1 from tab where input in ( 13, 10, 23, 35 ) );
```

gives "same" as output if met the value in the comma seperated list.